# Find all solutions to $x^3-5x+10=2^y$, where $x,y\in\mathbb{N}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

I believe $(2;3)$ is the only solution.

I managed to prove that for the equality to be true, $x\equiv2\ (mod\ 4)$ has to be true, but that approach didn't lead me anywhere.

Comment: Can you clarify what is $n$? Did you mean $ x\equiv 2$? If so, can you show that step?

Comment: Did mean $x\equiv2\ (mod\ 4)$. The step is quite primitive, plugging in $x\equiv0,1,3$ shows that the left-hand side doesn't divide by $4$, so the equality is only true if the right-hand side is exactly $2$, which doesn't happen for any natural $(x;y)$.

Comment: @CalvinLin Is this an elliptic curve? I think it can not be solved completely by elementary algebra.

Comment: @lonestudent See Ivan's solution in the dupe. The idea is to show that $ 3 \mid y$, and so we can now compare these cubes, to show that the only solutions must be small enough.

Comment: @CalvinLin Yes I will read.  Is the equation an elliptic curve?  I wanted to know.

Comment: @lonestudent No it's not. You might be thinking of $y^2 = x^3 - 5x + 10$.

Comment: @CalvinLin Thank you.I got it.

Comment: @lonestudent Just if you are interested: you can solve this problem using elliptic curves. We only have to find integral points on two elliptic curves: $y^2 = x^3 - 5x + 10$ and $2y^2 = x^3 - 5x + 10$. Both can be solved with a computer algebra system.